# Jquery clicking on dot changing div

Tags: jquery, html

Ey, I have 3 dots in a block. I have 3 versions of that block. Every dot clicked needs to show another one and hide the other so you dont see the other blocks text etc. I have tried it with an copy pasted jquery function I used for something similar but it only worked for 1 click, after that the function stopped. So my question is what is the best way to get this working?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="CalculatorRight" style="padding-bottom: 11px;">
  <div class="DefaultSummary" id="schermpje1">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">yeet1</h1>
    <!-- dots -->
    <div style="text-align:center; float:middle bottom;position: absolute;bottom:0;left: 141px;">
      <span id="dot1" class="dot"></span>
      <span id="dot2" class="dot"></span>
      <span id="dot3" class="dot"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="CalculatorRight">
    <div class="DefaultSummary" id="schermpje2" style="display:none">
      <h1>yeet2</h1>
      <!-- dots -->
      <div style="text-align:center; float:middle bottom;position: absolute;bottom:0;left: 141px;">
        <span id="dot1" class="dot"></span>
        <span id="dot2" class="dot"></span>
        <span id="dot3" class="dot"></span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="CalculatorRight">
      <div class="DefaultSummary" id="schermpje3" style="display:none">
        <!-- form -->
        <!-- <div class="row">
           <form class="col s12">
             <div class="row">
               <div class="input-field col s6">
                 <input placeholder="Placeholder" id="first_name" type="text" class="validate">
                 <label for="first_name">First Name</label>
               </div>
               <div class="input-field col s6">
                 <input id="last_name" type="text" class="validate">
                 <label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
               </div>
             </div>
           </form>
         </div> -->
         <!-- form -->
         <h1>yeet3</h1>
         <!-- dots -->
         <div style="text-align:center; float:middle bottom;position: absolute;bottom:0;left: 141px;">
           <span id="dot1" class="dot"></span>
           <span id="dot2" class="dot"></span>
           <span id="dot3" class="dot"></span>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I press one of the dots I want it to switch between Defaultsummary's.

**Tried this but stops working after 1 time use:**

```
$(function() {
      $('#dot1').on('click', function() {
        $('#schermpje1').show();
        $('#schermpje2').hide();
        $('#schermpje3').hide();
      })

      $('#dot2').on('click', function() {
        $('#schermpje2').show();
        $('#schermpje3').hide();
        $('#schermpje1').hide();
      })
        $('#dot3').on('click', function() {
        $('#schermpje3').show();
        $('#schermpje2').hide();
        $('#schermpje1').hide();
      })
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click','#dot1',function(){
     $('#schermpje1').show();
     $('#schermpje2, #schermpje3').hide();
});

$(document).on('click','#dot2',function(){
    $('#schermpje2').show();
    $('#schermpje1, #schermpje3').hide();
});

$(document).on('click','#dot3',function(){
    $('#schermpje3').show();
    $('#schermpje1, #schermpje2').hide();
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.